# How to pivot a single column long dataframe into a single row wide dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I see there are many questions on Stack Overflow and other places online regarding pivoting dataframes into wide and long format. But I don't see any clear, simple examples of just transposing or pivoting a single column dataframe into a single row, "pivot wide" dataframe. Any recommendations for an easy way to do this? I'm fine with base R, dplyr, data.table, tidyr, etc. Below I illustrate what I'm trying to do, with the code for a super-simple single column dataframe at the bottom. This is exactly representative of the larger reactive dataframe I'm wrestling with. Very important to preserve the `row.names` of my `test` dataframe and transpose them into column names for the new pivoted data frame, and they need to be column names and not just a first row of a 2 row dataframe.

[image]

Code for example dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(c(1:5), row.names = LETTERS[1:5])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier after transposing

```
as.data.frame(t(unname(test)))
  A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: AAAHHHH how did I forget `t()`! One of the first things I learned in R! Akrun answering this question is like Michael Jordan teaching first graders how to play basketball. You deserve a soft ball every now and then!